# Removing cancelled timers from a table to avoid 'warning: timer.pause cannot pause an expired timer id'

Tags: timer, lua, coronasdk, lua-table, cancellation

In corona SDK I am trying to remove timers from a table when they are cancelled to avoid receiving the terminal warning:

> audio.pause/resume cannot pause/resume a timerid that is already expired.

(After a while they build up to a lot!)

I can remove timers that fire once or more using this in the end of the timers function:

```
for k,v in pairs ( timers ) do
  if ( v == e.source ) then
    table.remove ( timers, k )
    print ( "Complete: "..k, e.source, #timers )
  end
end
```

(this checks if the timer in the table is the same as the one that sent the function and removes it if it is)

or if fires more than once but not never-ending then check how many counts it's done then call the above for loop.

What I cannot figure out is how to do this when cancelling timers, so if I cancel a timer that's somewhere in the table I want to remove it from that table but can't because the order's been all jumbled up from other timers being removed / expiring etc. please someone help!!

(Also on a side not just wondered if apple/google would reject an app for having these terminal warnings? I'm guessing if the game is used for an extended period of time then there will be an excessive amount of these warnings and this isn't professional?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
local i = 1
for k,v in pairs ( timers ) do
    if ( v == e.source ) then
        table.remove ( timers, i )
    else
        i = i + 1
    end
end
```

And here is how it works. You iterate through k elements in timers table. You start from element at index no. 1. If it equals e.source, then you remove it and start once again from i = 1 element. It's because the previous 1st element is already removed, so previously 2nd element is now 1st. But if v is not equal to e.source, then you leave it on 1st index and start to check 2nd till you find it is again not equal to e.source

Comment: i already implemented e.source (di you not see i posted above?)

Comment: I have solved it for neverending timers by using:

`local i = 1`
`for k,v in pairs ( timers ) do`
    `if ( v == enemyTimer ) then`
        `table.remove ( timers, i )`
    `else`

        `i = i + 1`
    `end`
`end`